# React.js get data from js array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';

import ProjectsData from './projects.js';

class SingleProject extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="info-project-wrapper">
                <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
                <span className="show-for-large">{this.props.by}</span>
                <ul className="project-links show-for-large">
                    <li>{this.props.links}</li>
                </ul>
                <div className="info-project">
                    <p>VIEW NOW</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class SingleProjectWrapper extends React.Component {
    render () {
        var projects = [];
        this.props.projects.forEach(function(project, i){
            projects.push(<SingleProject title={project.title}  
                             by={project.by}
                             links={projects.links}
                             key={i} />);
        });
        return (
            <div className="single-project project-4">
                {projects}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Projects extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <section>
            <SingleProjectWrapper projects={ProjectsData} />
        </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

and "projectsData" comes from:

```
var projects = [
    {
        title: 'title1',
        by: 'dfs',
        links: ['link-1', 'link-2', 'link-3']
    },
    {
        title: 'title2',
        by: 'sdfsd',
        links: ['link-1', 'link-2', 'link-3']
    },
    {
        title: 'title3',
        by: 'sfsf',
        links: ['link-1', 'link-2', 'link-3']
    },
    {
        title: 'title4',
        by: 'sdffd',
        links: ['link-1', 'link-2', 'link-3']
    }
];

export default projects;
```

most of the data gets displayed correctly apart from `<li>{this.props.links}</li>`. I only get an empty `<li></li>` as opposed to "link-1, link-2 and link-3" for each.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but you have a misspelling in the links code:  `links={projects.links}`.  Should be `links={project.links}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to iterate over the array of links, React doesn't do anything fancy with arrays.

So instead of;

```
<ul className="project-links show-for-large">
  <li>{this.props.links}</li>
</ul>
```

You'll need to do;

```
<ul className="project-links show-for-large">
    {this.props.links.map(i => <li>i</li>)}
</ul>
```